# Unexpected end of json error when creating a new angular project via Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular

Node v12.14.1
npm v6.13.4
angular-cli v8.3.22

Anytime I try to create a project with angular cli such as "ng new test-app" then I end up with this error:

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pes/minimist":"^1.1.2'

The module where it errors changes. It is not always '...pes/minimist":"^1.1.2'.

I have tried doing npm cache clean --force, uninstalling and reinstalling node, running in command prompt as admin and not as admin. Those were the suggestions I found online.

Anyone know of any other solution that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Do let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: I stopped getting that error but then I was getting another one that started with "npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall unlink". I tried deactivating my antivirus and made sure I was running command prompt as admin. No luck. I just decided to downgrade angular cli to v8.2.2 and now it works. Nothing special about that version. I just randomly picked it. I don't know whats up with the latest version of angular/cli and my environment.